# Extendible CLI for my application

Tags: java, spring

I maintain an application that is used internally for testing infrastructure. Usually, it just has to be run on one device during the whole test, but occasionally we need to get information out of this application, or manipulate it in runtime.
For this said purpose, it has a CLI, but alas, here are the instructions I wrote for myself as to how new CLI commands should be added:

"""

***Adding CLI commands***

- *Create a classes for the new command in cli/client/commands/{category}/CLINewCommand.java and cli/server/commands/{category}/NewCommand.java*
- *The CLI* class must extend CLICOnfigCmd and implement CLICommand.*
- *Add the command to the enumeration in cli/client/commands/SimServerCmd.java and use the enumerated value in cli/client/commands/CLICommandFactory.java*
- *Add the command class to cli/server/RepositoryInfo.java and add a public method to invoke it's server side command. This command has to be added to the interface RepositoryInfoMBean as well.*
- *Initialize the new objects in the config/applicationContext.xml and config/cliApplicationContext.xml. Add strings to print in config/simulator_cli_conf.properties*

"""

So if you managed to follow my quirky self-discovered instructions, in order to add a CLI command you need to create 2 classes for the command, edit 4 different classes and then edit two Spring configuration files and one property file.

For adding. Just. One. Command.

Needless to say, many required CLI features are missing.

Do you have suggestions for a better design? Better would be easily extendible.

Comment: Adding a command means - a new input parameter and value via console, is that a correct assumption ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Commons CLI.  It does a good job of preventing me from thinking about the cli.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this approach, you might consider using code generation (e.g. with the [Eclipse Modeling toolchain](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/)), however this adds a lot of complexity to your development process - I'm not sure if it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) system.  Have your `CLICommand` interface contain the following, at least:

```
void execute(MyApplication app);
String cliName();
void setArgument(String argument);
```

Create a jar for each new command, and put into the `META-INF/services/com.example.CLICommand` file the fully-qualified name of the new command class. In your application class, query the class path with:

```
 private static ServiceLoader<CLICommand> cliLoader
     = ServiceLoader.load(CLICommand.class);
```

and iterate through the commands in `cliLoader` to get the command-line option name.

For example,

```
public class VerboseCommand {
    private boolean verbose = false;
    public String cliName() {
        return "verbose";
    }

    public void setArgument(String argument) {
        if (argument != null && !argument.isEmpty()) {
            this.verbose = Boolean.valueOf(argument);
        } else {
            this.verbose = true;
        }
    }
    public void execute(MyApplication app) {
        app.setVerbose(verbose);
    }
}
```

Now, if somebody executes the command `verbose`, the application sees the line, breaks it up into arguments, uses looks up `verbose` and finds the `VerboseCommand` instance, and sends it a null or empty string.  The command then sets the application's `verbose` attribute to true.

For people who like that sort of thing, however, use JMX too.

Comment: Some more investigation revealed to me that JMX is in fact being used. I'll read more about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly all your commands will be spring beans and they have to implement a specific (marker)interface?

If that's the case what about this.

- Command interface defines one method execute(properties) that needs to be implemented.
- Command service provides the cli facility to choose a command and execute it. Here you can just autowire all discovered commands as a list and the facility uses it.

  The only issue I see here is how to tell which package to scan if the commands do not need to be in a specific package. If you use this cli only internally I would specific a top level package these commands need to be defined in and hook the component scan on this package so all commands can be discovered by spring without any configuration.

All you need to implement is one command class annotated with @Component.